# zsh glob qualifiers in middle of path

Tags: zsh

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p a/1
$ ln -s a b
```

Globbing for directories, I get the directory within the symlink too:

```
$ print -l */*(/)
a/1
b/1
```

How can I restrict the globbing for the first directory level to directories only, excluding symlinks? The obvious doesn't work:

```
$ print -l *(/)/*(/)
zsh: bad pattern: *(/)/*(/)
```

More generally, how can I specify glob qualifiers for intermediate path components? In spirit:

```
$ print -l a(...)/b(...)/c(...)/d(...)/e(...)/f(...)
```

where `(...)` denotes glob qualifiers for the respective path components.

Comment: Possibly a special case of what you are asking, but `**` does not follow symbolic links. `print -l **/1` in your example would only match `a/1`, not `b/1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind `a` itself appearing in your list, then this should do the trick:

```bash
# ** doesn't follow symlinks.
print -l **/*(/)
```

If you want only subdirs, then you'll need to use two patterns, instead of one:

```bash
# Make an array with all dirs that are in the pwd.
tmp=( *(/) )

# $^tmp applies brace expansion on the array.
# (N) ignores 'file not found' errors, in case tmp contains dirs w/out children.
print -l $^tmp/*(/N)
```

This way, you can also have different glob qualifiers for each part in your path, but you'll have to make a separate parameter for each.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) suggests that glob qualifiers may be used only at the end of a pattern:

> Patterns used for filename generation may end in a list of qualifiers enclosed in parentheses. The qualifiers specify which filenames that otherwise match the given pattern will be inserted in the argument list.

While less convenient than a glob, what you are trying to achieve could be done with `find`:

```
find -H . ! -path . -type d -links 2 | xargs
./a/1
```